# Append async ahead of render() in react?

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I have the following code.

```
searchMemberPromise() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve('foo');
            }, 1000);
        });
    }

    async searchMember() {
        let out = await this.searchMemberPromise();
        return out;
    }


    async render() {

        let out = await this.searchMember();
        console.log(out);

        return (
            <Router history={history}>
            ... more code here
```

I try to wait for the final result of await this.searchMember. To do so, I append async before render().

The error I got is

```
Uncaught Error: _default.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

I think I can do something like this, but I want to remove the callback style.

```
let promise = this.searchMember()
promise.then((res) => { console.log(res) })
```

Comment: Why make `render()` async, instead of letting its execution be tied to state/props change in the usual way? (I'm sure your real goal is not to resolve foo after 1 second. What is your real goal?)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are thinking of it in the wrong way.

You want to delay rendering the html until the promise is resolved so use conditional rendering and component state.

```
class Component extends Component {
    state: {
        loaded: false,
        out: null
    }
    searchMemberPromise() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve('foo');
            }, 1000);
        });
    }

    searchMember = async  () => {
        let out = await this.searchMemberPromise();
        this.setState({loaded: true, out});
        return;
    }
    render() {
        const { loaded, out } = this.state;
        if (!loaded) {
            return null;
        } else {
            console.log(out);
            return (
                <div>hello world</div>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Please note how the `searchMember` method is now an arrow function so that it has access to the `this` reference